# Drop unused levels from a factor after filtering data frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I used dplyr function to create a new data sets which contain the names that have less than 4 rows.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"), x = 1:9)

aa = df %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    filter(n() < 4)
```

But when I type

```
table(aa$name)
```

I get,

```
a b c 
3 2 0
```

I would like to have my output as follow

```
a b 
3 2
```

How to completely separate new frame aa from df?

Comment: You may use `droplevels` to drop unused factor levels (like c)

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was exactly looking for.

Answer (score 7):

To complete your answer and KoenV's comment you can just, write your solution in one line or apply the function `factor` will remove the unused levels:

```
table(droplevels(aa$name))
table(factor(aa$name))
```

or because you are using `dplyr` add `droplevels` at the end:

```
aa <- df %>%
       group_by(name) %>%
       filter(n() < 4) %>% 
       droplevels()
table(aa$name)

# Without using table
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  filter(count < 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 aaNew <- droplevels(aa)
 table(aa$name)
```

Comment: Please add a small explanation to your answer

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged; would you mind explaining what you're doing so future readers can more easily understand?